# Haskell unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, haskell

I'm new to haskell and working on unit testing, however I find the ecosystem to be very confusing.  I'm confused as to the relationship between HTF and HUnit.

In some examples I see you set up test cases, export them in an tests list, and then run in ghci with `runTestsTT` (like [this HUnit example](http://hunit.sourceforge.net/HUnit-1.0/Guide.html)).

In other examples, you create a test runner tied into the cabal file that uses some preprocessor magic to find your tests like in this [git example](https://github.com/skogsbaer/HTF/blob/master/sample/TestMain.hs).  Also it seems that HTF tests need to be prefixed with `test_` or they aren't run? I had a hard time finding any documentation on that, I just noticed the pattern that everyone had.

Anyways, can someone help sort this out for me? What is considered the standard way of doing things in Haskell? What are the best practices? What is the easiest to set up and maintain?

Comment: Have you looked at the QuickCheck library?  I've always found it pretty easy to use.

Comment: Yeah, but quick check is a different use case, that's for type based testing, which isn't what I want right now. I'd be interested to know how to integrate that as well though once I wrap my head around how htf and hunit relate

Comment: https://twitter.com/HaskellTips/status/425793151660331008 says to prefer `tasty` over `test-framework` (HTF?), but I also see that HTF got an small update last week, after several months of quiey.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Generally, any significant Haskell project is run with [Cabal](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/). This takes care of building, distribution, documentation (with the help of haddock), and testing.

The standard approach is to put your tests in the `test` directory and then set up a test suite in your `.cabal` file. This is detailed in the [user manual](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#test-suites). Here's what the test suite for one of my projects looks like

```
Test-Suite test-melody
  type:               exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is:            Main.hs
  hs-source-dirs:     test
  build-depends:      base >=4.6 && <4.7,
                      test-framework,
                      test-framework-hunit,
                      HUnit,
                      containers == 0.5.*
```

Then in the file `test/Main.hs`

```
import Test.HUnit
import Test.Framework
import Test.Framework.Providers.HUnit
import Data.Monoid
import Control.Monad
import Utils

pushTest :: Assertion
pushTest = [NumLit 1] ^? push (NumLit 1)

pushPopTest :: Assertion
pushPopTest = [] ^? (push (NumLit 0) >> void pop)

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMainWithOpts
       [testCase "push" pushTest
       ,testCase "push-pop" pushPopTest]
       mempty
```

Where `Utils` defines some nicer interfaces over [HUnit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HUnit).

For lighter-weight testing, I strongly recommend you use [QuickCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.6). It lets you write short properties and test them over a series of random inputs. For example:

```
 -- Tests.hs
 import Test.QuickCheck

 prop_reverseReverse :: [Int] -> Bool
 prop_reverseReverse xs = reverse (reverse xs) == xs
```

And then

```
 $ ghci Tests.hs
 > import Test.QuickCheck
 > quickCheck prop_reverseReverse
 .... Passed Tests (100/100)
```

Comment: As a project grows you have to maintain the exported test list? Seems error prone. I guess I'm still confused as to how this related to the auto exported preprocessor method? I see a lot of unit testing examples but it's all different

Comment: @devshorts The list of tests let's you name each test individually. I do believe that there are frameworks that will automagically run your tests, but I usually have about 10 tests per file so maintaining such small lists is quite easy.

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate how you use this method with more than one test file? Is the main runner separate or usually part of the test fixture?

Comment: @devshorts I split my tests apart and from each module export the list of tests with their names. Then in main, I combine the lists and run them.

Comment: I used this answer to write the test framework for this little project: https://github.com/siddharthist/m3u-convert Thanks to @jozefg, and I hope the example helps everyone :-)

Comment: after taking a look into cabal documentation on `detailed-0.9`: it seems to me that this answer is the state-of-the-art "I want to do straightforward unit testing"-setup for ghc/cabal. I find it a bit awkward to rely on the three packages `test-framework`, `HUnit`, and `test-framework-hunit` for something this basic. And it looks it has been like that for 8 years by now.

Answer (score 39):

I'm also newbie haskeller and I've found this introduction really helpful: "[Getting started with HUnit](http://archive.li/4NasW)". To summarize, I'll put here simple testing example of HUnit usage without `.cabal` project file:

Let's assume that we have module `SafePrelude.hs`:

```
module SafePrelude where

safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead []    = Nothing
safeHead (x:_) = Just x
```

we can put tests into `TestSafePrelude.hs` as follows:

```
module TestSafePrelude where

import Test.HUnit
import SafePrelude

testSafeHeadForEmptyList :: Test
testSafeHeadForEmptyList = 
    TestCase $ assertEqual "Should return Nothing for empty list"
                           Nothing (safeHead ([]::[Int]))

testSafeHeadForNonEmptyList :: Test
testSafeHeadForNonEmptyList =
    TestCase $ assertEqual "Should return (Just head) for non empty list" (Just 1)
               (safeHead ([1]::[Int]))

main :: IO Counts
main = runTestTT $ TestList [testSafeHeadForEmptyList, testSafeHeadForNonEmptyList]
```

Now it's easy to run tests using `ghc`:

```
runghc TestSafePrelude.hs
```

or `hugs` - in this case `TestSafePrelude.hs` has to be renamed to `Main.hs` (as far as I'm familiar with hugs) (don't forget to change module header too):

```
runhugs Main.hs
```

or any other `haskell` compiler ;-)

Of course there is more then that in `HUnit`, so I really recommend to read suggested tutorial and library [User's Guide](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HUnit_1.0_User's_Guide).

Comment: Hello, link to the Getting started with HUnit is broken

Comment: It looks like the link has been fixed, referring now to an archived version of the page.

Answer (score 8):

You've had answers to most of your questions, but you also asked about HTF, and how that works.

[HTF](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTF-0.13.1.0) is a framework that is designed for both unit testing -- it is backwards compatible with HUnit (it integrates and wraps it to provide extra functions) -- and property-based testing -- it integrates with quickcheck. It uses a preprocessor to locate tests so that you don't have to manually build a list.  The preprocessor is added to your test source files using a pragma:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -F -pgmF htfpp #-}
```

(alternatively, I guess you could add the same options to your  `ghc-options` property in your cabal file, but I've never tried this so don't know if it is useful or not).

The preprocessor scans your module for top-level functions named `test_xxxx` or `prop_xxxx` and adds them to a list of tests for the module.  You can either use this list directly by putting a `main` function in the module and running them (`main = htfMain htf_thisModuleTests`) or export them from the module, and have a main test program for multiple modules, which imports the modules with tests and runs all of them:

```
import {-@ HTF_TESTS @-} ModuleA
import {-@ HTF_TESTS @-} ModuleB
main :: IO ()
main = htfMain htf_importedTests
```

This program can be integrated with cabal using the technique described by @jozefg, or loaded into ghci and run interactively (although not on Windows - see https://github.com/skogsbaer/HTF/issues/60 for details).

[Tasty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty) is another alternative that provides a way of integrating different kinds of tests.  It doesn't have a preprocessor like HTF, but has a module that [performs similar functions using Template Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-th).  Like HTF, it also relies on naming convention to identify your tests (in this case, `case_xxxx` rather than `test_xxxx`). In addition to HUnit and QuickCheck tests, it also has modules for handling a number of other test types.