# Test a function's type

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331209/haskell-unit-testing/21419654#21419654) answer and I would also like to test the type of my functions, if there is a way to do it.
Here is an example : **test.hs**

```
module Test where
import Test.HUnit

test1 = TestCase (assertEqual "test1" 3 (length [1,2,3]))
tests = TestList [test1]

main :: IO Counts
main = runTestTT tests
```

I'm running the code with **`runghc test.hs`** and I get:

```
Cases: 1  Tried: 1  Errors: 0  Failures: 0
```

Now, how can I test the type for the `length` function ?

I have already tried adding a second test `test2 = TestCase (assertEqual "test2" "length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int" :type length)`, but I get this **error** `test.hs:5:77: parse error on input 'type'`.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Writing a test for a *type* is **almost definitely not what you want**. Since Haskell is statically typed, the compiler automatically checks types for you when you compile, with no need to run any code or tests. If `length` did not have a compatible type, you would get a type error if you tried to load the code at all.

`:type` is a special command from `ghci`, not actual Haskell syntax. You can't use it directly in a normal program. There are ways to get a value representing a type but they're somewhat complicated and, again, almost definitely not what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate: I could imagine wanting something like this for a library that had e.g. a forwards-compatible interface and an "internal" interface; then you might want tests that check that no hapless developer inadvertently changes the type of some part of the forwards-compatible interface. (The library interface could certainly contain operations that are useful to library consumers, but not actually called anywhere by the library itself, hence would not cause compile failure if their types changed.)

Answer (score 3):

Although I agree with the other answer that the question smells, I think it is worth giving a direct answer anyway. You could put a type assertion in your test suite like this:

```
module Test where

check_type_of_length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int
check_type_of_length = length
```

If `length` can not be given the type you requested, the module will not compile. However, this is not a perfect test: if the type of `length` is actually *more* polymorphic than the type you demand, this will still "pass"; thus, for example, the following module still compiles, even though `undefined` does not have exactly the type `Foldable t => t a -> Int`.

```
module Test where

check_type_of_length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int
check_type_of_length = undefined
```

We can make the test a bit more precise if you want to check a monomorphic type. The idea is to use `Typeable`, as suggested by @dfeuer. That would look like this:

```
module Test where

import Data.Typeable

test_type_of_not :: Bool
test_type_of_not = typeOf not == typeOf (undefined :: Bool -> Bool)
```

If `not` has the monomorphic type `Bool -> Bool`, then `test_type_of_not` will be `True`; if it has a different monomorphic type, it will be `False`; and if `not` suddenly becomes polymorphic, the module will fail to compile with an ambiguity error.

I do not know an analogous way to test that a polymorphic type does not become more polymorphic; you could perhaps do something nasty like running a short bash script that does

```
echo :t length | ghci
```

and checking its output, or something more direct with the GHC API. However, an approach like this is likely to be *very* fragile.

Comment: The most direct way by far (much easier than running GHCi from your program) is to use `typeRep :: forall proxy a. Typeable a => proxy a -> TypeRep`. You can actually print those out.

Comment: Urk... I guess `Typeable` probably has issues dealing with polymorphic things. *sigh*

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks for the suggestion. I've included some notes about `Typeable`.