# Haskell: Multiple Assertions in Unit Testing?

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, testing, assertion, hunit

I looked up a similar topic and found this snippet of code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21419654/14386048

To quote:
Let's assume that we have module `SafePrelude.hs`:

```
module SafePrelude where

safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead []    = Nothing
safeHead (x:_) = Just x
```

we can put tests into `TestSafePrelude.hs` as follows:

```
module TestSafePrelude where

import Test.HUnit
import SafePrelude

testSafeHeadForEmptyList :: Test
testSafeHeadForEmptyList = 
    TestCase $ assertEqual "Should return Nothing for empty list"
                           Nothing (safeHead ([]::[Int]))

testSafeHeadForNonEmptyList :: Test
testSafeHeadForNonEmptyList =
    TestCase $ assertEqual "Should return (Just head) for non empty list" (Just 1)
               (safeHead ([1]::[Int]))

main :: IO Counts
main = runTestTT $ TestList [testSafeHeadForEmptyList, testSafeHeadForNonEmptyList]
```

-- End Quote --
Is it possible to have multiple assertions within, let's say, `testSafeHeadForEmptyList`? I'm trying to categorize my test samples of similar cases, but just different variations. I want to avoid something like this below (assume each assert equal has a different variation, but all should return nothing, for example):

```
testSafeHeadForEmptyList :: Test
testSafeHeadForEmptyList = 
    TestCase $ assertEqual "Should return Nothing for empty list"
                           Nothing (safeHead ([]::[Int]))
testSafeHeadForEmptyList2 :: Test
testSafeHeadForEmptyList2 = 
    TestCase $ assertEqual "Should return Nothing for empty list"
                           Nothing (safeHead ([]::[Int]))
...
testSafeHeadForEmptyList99 :: Test
testSafeHeadForEmptyList99 = 
    TestCase $ assertEqual "Should return Nothing for empty list"
                           Nothing (safeHead ([]::[Int]))
```

Is this possible in Haskell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look carefully here: [`Test`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HUnit-1.6.2.0/docs/Test-HUnit-Base.html#t:Test) - you see that `TestCase` and `TestList` are data-constructors of the `Test` type - so you should be able to do something like this:

```hs
testSafeHeadForEmptyList :: Test
testSafeHeadForEmptyList = TestList $
    [ TestCase $ assertEqual "Should return Nothing for empty list"
                             Nothing (safeHead ([]::[Int]))
    , TestCase $ assertEqual "Should return Nothing for empty list"
                             Nothing (safeHead ([]::[Int]))
    ...
    , TestCase $ assertEqual "Should return Nothing for empty list"
                             Nothing (safeHead ([]::[Int]))
    ]
```

or even `fmap` the `TestCase`-constructor if you like:

```hs
testSafeHeadForEmptyList :: Test
testSafeHeadForEmptyList = TestList $ fmap TestCase
    [ assertEqual "Should return Nothing for empty list"
                  Nothing (safeHead ([]::[Int]))
    , assertEqual "Should return Nothing for empty list"
                  Nothing (safeHead ([]::[Int]))
    ...
    , assertEqual "Should return Nothing for empty list"
                  Nothing (safeHead ([]::[Int]))
    ]
```

and of course `TestLabel` is a constructor as well so you can stick a Label to it:

```hs
testSafeHeadForEmptyList :: Test
testSafeHeadForEmptyList = 
  TestLabel "safe head for empty list" $ TestList $ fmap TestCase
    [ assertEqual "Should return Nothing for empty list"
                  Nothing (safeHead ([]::[Int]))
    , assertEqual "Should return Nothing for empty list"
                  Nothing (safeHead ([]::[Int]))
    ...
    , assertEqual "Should return Nothing for empty list"
                  Nothing (safeHead ([]::[Int]))
    ]
```

(you could use `(~:)` for that too of course)

Comment: This was an exemplary comment, thank you so much for the handy template variations in the ways of setting up multiple assertions. I especially found the third method very useful for organizing my test cases by label. Cheers for the test documentation as well!